# Web Scraping - HTTP Error 403: Forbidden - Ziprecruiter

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I am trying to scrape data from https://www.ziprecruiter.com/jobs-search?search=python&location=Ontario&company=&layout=&days=1

I tried using the above link and seems to work fine inside a browser. But, when I use the code below to get the data from the website in python, it doesn't seem to load the page properly.

Looks like it loads a page that is encrypted.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.ziprecruiter.com/jobs-search?search=python&location=Ontario&company=&layout=&days=1')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

print (soup)
```

Comment: did you try with another page? your user agent is too cheap... retry Attempt 3 with a proper user-agent and, in case, report the error

Comment: I was not the one who down-vote your question... you have showed a clear attempt to reach a solution in my opinion. My comment was about to add a better user-agent, smt like `'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'`. If you get such response it is clear that the your request was detected as bot and access deny

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your solutions and got - Response [403]. I think they have some anti-scraper security checks as you mentioned.

Comment: @ Henul did you try with selenium? I tried it out and I could fetch the source page

Comment: I forgot to copy a line, `implicitly_wait` so that has enough time to render the full page. Sorry for that, answer already updated

Comment: Yes, I just tried your answer and it looks like it is not loading the URL. But, it does open the browser and shows `data:,` in the URL input space.

Comment: @cards I finally found a solutions to this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was't able to find a direct answer to this. But this works fine.

I basically added a chrome driver to get the data. Here's how:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver_location = #C/program/.... (chromedriver location)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_location)

driver.get('https://www.ziprecruiter.com/jobs-search?search=python&location=Ontario&company=&layout=&days=1')

content = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

cards = soup.find_all('div','job_content')
```

Comment: good! well... I don't know why with the firefox drivers didn't work... much easier:) maybe was because of the headless option?

Comment: Yes, that could have caused the issue.